# How to fix crackling sound in Ubunu 20.04 when laptop is charging?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, power-management, alsa, battery

I recently purchased a Dell Inspiron 2-in-1 5491. Everything works great except for the audio - which has an persistent crackle and hiss when the laptop is charging; as soon as I pull the power cable out, the audio issues stop.

Any advice on how to fix? It's driving me nuts!

```
$ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: inspiron Kernel: 5.4.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.2 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: Dell product: Inspiron 5491 2n1 v: N/A 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 0GJNK1 v: A00 serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: Dell v: 1.5.0 date: 02/04/2020 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-37-generic

$ dpkg -l | grep -e pulse -e alsa
ii  alsa-base                                  1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                  all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-oss                                   1.1.8-1                               amd64        ALSA wrapper for OSS applications
ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.2-1                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.2-1                               all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu1                        amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                    1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64              1.16.2-1ubuntu2                       amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64              1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.3                  amd64        PulseAudio client libraries (glib support)
ii  libpulse0:amd64                            1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.3                  amd64        PulseAudio client libraries
ii  libpulsedsp:amd64                          1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.3                  amd64        PulseAudio OSS pre-load library
ii  pulseaudio                                 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.3                  amd64        PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.3                  amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils                           1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.3                  amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
```

Comment: Thats a bad ground somewhere.  The power supply or on board regulator is leaking power. Hardware and not software. New power supply/charger may fix the issue. Mostly likely the plug.

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu... You need better grounding somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was an extension plug that is probably not grounded correctly - when plugging the device directly into to the wall socket, I get clean audio.
Thanks @walttheboss and @Rinzwind!